# Drupal 8: The proper alternative to exit(); for terminating a request

Tags: 8

Does anybody know how to avoid the brutal PHP built-in exit(); function and use the "right" Drupal 8 class method to terminate the request? If so: a bit explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? Why would you want to return a json response anywhere else than in a controller, where you can just return it?

Answer (score 1):

You would have been looking for drupal_exit() in the past, but this was removed in D8. It is now advised to use the appropriate HTTP Exception. See the example on the change notice:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2017339

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for. I'm sending a response via 

      $response = new JsonResponse();
      $response->setData(array(
        'data' => 123
      ));
      $response->send();

Afterwards I do not want, that Drupal does any data output. But there might be any "terminate" events which should be triggered. With exit(); they are just killed and this is not good.

Comment: You might want to reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584341/symfony2-force-stop-code-execution-after-sendiing-response-headers